# JQuery get th or td text from tr empty spaces issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, whitespace

I'm using JQuery Mobile table:

```
<table data-role="table" id="productTable" data-mode="reflow" class="tablesorter ui-responsive table-stroke my-custom-breakpoint">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-priority="1">
                            ID
                        </th>

                        ...

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="productRepeater" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class="item">
                                <th class="id">
                                    <%# Eval ("ID")%>
                                </th>

                                ...

                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Now I'm trying to extract all the ids form the  and put them in an array in my JavaScript below:

```
function viewSelectedDocuments() {
    var selectedIDs = [];    
    $("tr.item").each(function () {  
        var id = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
        var id = $.trim(id);
        alert(id);
        selectedIDs.push(id);
    });
}
```

This function is called when a button is clicked. However in the `var id` I'm not getting quite what I was expecting. Instead of the text from the cell say `"1"` I'm getting

```
"ID

                                    1"
```

and yes - `$.trim(id);` is not working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `var id = $(this).children().eq(0).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: @Ramunas if you can copy your code as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be easily solved with a bit of regex:

```
var id = $(this).children().eq(0).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

What I would suggest is to improve your structure a bit:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="item" data-id='<%# Eval ("ID")%>'>
        <th class="id">
            <%# Eval ("ID")%>
        </th>
        ...
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and

```
function viewSelectedDocuments() {
    var selectedIDs = [];    
    $("tr.item").each(function () {  
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        //var id = $.trim(id); <-- no need to trim anymore

        // depending on what your <%# Eval ("ID")%> you might still need regex
        // id = id.replace(/\s+/g, " "); // uncomment if needed
        alert(id);
        selectedIDs.push(id);
    });
}
```

Regex + jQuery's `text()` is a bit resource intensive as it does some DOM manipulations behind the scenes, while using `data()` is more or less reading attribute value